# MySQL Select multiple values and add to one column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to combine multiple rows column value into one column value. See pictures below for an example use case.

Sample data:

[image: Before]

Expected output:

[image: I need the view table like this]

Comment: share formatted text not image

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(kode_mk)`.

Comment: I can't see the image you sent to the question, please use the 3rd party to upload the image https://imgbb.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregated query with [aggregate function `GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT
    nim,
    nama,
    GROUP_CONCAT(kode_mk) kode_mk,
    GROUP_CONCAT(nama_mk) nama_mk,
    GROUP_CONCAT(sks) sks,
    SUM(sks) count_sks
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 
    nim, 
    nama
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Nim, Nama, group_concat(Kode_mk), group_concat(Nama_mk) Nama_mk, group_concat(sks) sks, Count_sks from <tableName> group by Nim
```

try this out.

Visit Group_concat [documentation](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) for more reference